# Is it bad practice to change HTML files on the fly with express?

Tags: javascript, express

I had a problem. I wanted to access some env vars inside the browser.

I was doing that like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.end.NODE_ENV),
    'API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL)
})
```

That was working great, but it runs on build time and I needed the variables to change on run time.

I have a simple express server to run my app. To do what I needed this was my solution:

```
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;
const parser = new Transform();
parser._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
  const str = data.toString().replace('<head>', `<head>
    <script>
      const API_URL = "${process.env.API_URL}"
      const NODE_ENV = "${process.env.NODE_ENV}"
    </script>`);
  this.push(str);
  done();
};

if (fs.existsSync(DIST_DIR)) {
  app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR))
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.write('<!-- Begin stream -->\n');
    fs.createReadStream(HTML_FILE)
      .pipe(parser)
      .on('end', () => {
        res.write('\n<!-- End stream -->')
      })
      .pipe(res);
  })
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  })
} else {
  throw new Error ("No build was found in the ../dist folder. Please run 'npm run build'.")
}
```

I basically change my index.html file on the fly while serving it. It feels like bad practice but at the same time it works so well.

What do you guys think about it? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, that's fine. This is exactly how templating systems work.

Comment: Though you could improve performance by loading the HTML file into memory once, instead of reading it from disk every time.

Comment: Will do! Thanks :) I am having another problem with this, when I change routes I get a "write after end" error. Do you know what that is about?

Comment: I'm not a Node/Express user, but I'm assuming you shouldn't call `res.write()` inside your `on('end'` handler function.